# How do I change the width of a grid on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the width of the columns but I'm not really sure how to do it. I've tried a lot of things but they seem not to be working. Here is my code

```css
.left-box {
    background-color: green;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" id="left-box">
        <h6>About me</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h6>About me</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h6>About me</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to change the width with a CSS class on an id. Change your CSS to #left-box{...}.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ID` it should call as `#Example` in css, if it is a `class`, it should call as `.Example`.

But you can handle the column widths from bootstrap grid as well. Check the following documentation for bootstrap 3.3 if you are using it.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

If it is bootstrap 4,
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```css
#left-box {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" id="left-box">
    <h6>About me</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h6>About me</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h6>About me</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap system works based on it's classes, being col-*-6 => width 50%, since it's half of the 12 possible columns.

If you want a 20%ish column you can use `<div class="col-xs-2"></div>`

Read more about how works the grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/